# ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: iconv-lite

Tags: encoding, npm, gulp, webpack

My project was working perfectly fine.. But after doing a git push, I'm suddenly getting an error when I run `gulp`:

```
{ [Error: ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: 
/Users/xyz/project/node_modules/iconv-lite/encodings/tables/gb18030-ranges.json 
Line 1: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {"uChars":[128,16 ....
```

Why is this happening? I have uninstalled and reinstalled this module `iconv-lite`, but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 17):

I received this same exact error.  You'll want to install a JSON loader module.  I'm using [json-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader) in this example.

```
npm install json-loader --save
```

Then, you need to add this loader to your webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Still I can't help but wonder why Webpack doesn't natively recognize JSON, given that it's the built-in data format for the language Webpack is written in...

Comment: Thanks for this, I can run right now, but I got the warning message:

```
WARNING in ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js
Critical dependencies:
9:12-34 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js 9:12-34
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this dependency by an indirect dependency on `node-fetch` and fixed the issue by adding the following to my webpack.config.js:

```
externals: {
    'node-fetch': 'fetch'
}
```

Comment: Great. This was it for me. It makes perfect sense as it bypasses the issue on browser side.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what was going on at first because I had a JSON loader configured and everything.  Then I realized that the package Lokka (that I'm using) uses `node-fetch`, and that made me think to try this fix.  Worked great :)

Answer (score -1):

Deleting the file solved the issue.

Comment: perfect solution! just comes to my list right after "did you tried to turn off and on again?".. now with "did you delete the file? you know, THE file!... stupids" xD

Comment: Deleting a file that is part of a node module shouldn't be a serious solution.